# Best way to pass variables from Symfony2 to Angular scope

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

As a common scenario that many other developers face - we have a mature application based on Symfony2 / TWIG, and some of the html.twig templates got too much overloaded with jQuery code and hard to maintain. 
What about throwing away jQuery, and use Angular ?
Provided I have some basic knowledge about angular modules, controllers, services and scope, and a deep knowledge of Symfony2/TWIG, my fist problem is - **what is the best way to pass variables from my existing controllers/twig templates to angular controllers?**

I don't want to load scope through separate JSON call and a separate controller in Symfony2. Just want to use existing variables I have in twig.

One way to do is declare some global js variables:

```
<script>
var window.someVar = {{ twig_object | json_encode() }};
</script>
```

an then do smth like

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()">
<div ng-model="someVar"> .... </div>
</div>
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.init = function () {
    if (window['someVar']) {
        $scope['someVar'] = window['someVar'];
    }
};
```

But this seems too ugly for me (3 steps)
May it be simplified at least or done another way?

Comment: My own experience is that you will be constantly fighting AngularJS.  For me it ended up being easier to add a _format=json parameter to my routes and then just return json from the controller.  Keep AngularJS happy and twig out of the picture.  Plus you won't have to deal with the whole curly braces issue.

Comment: @Cerad I'm very curious about the curly brace issue. In MVC (which I use) we introduce server side variables with an at *@* symbol, but you use the same syntax client side here (for interpolation) as you do server side (for variables being passed down from the server)! Don't you run into issues from time to time, or is it OK because the server sees the code first?

Comment: @JMK - I don't understand your question.  I avoid the curly issue by keeping twig and angularjs templates in separate files.  The angularjs ones are served up directly without going through S2 at all.

Comment: @JMK - seems there is no any curly brace issue. I ususally use $interpolateProvider in my modules, to use [[ ]] for angular and leave {{ }} for Twig. Or I am overseeing smth?

Answer (score 7):

You can declare variables directly in ng-init, so:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="myModel.someVar='{{ twig_object | json_encode() }}';">
```

I'm more used to Razor in ASP.Net MVC but I assume the same principle applies here with Symfony2.

Also remember the double dot rule, you don't want value's declared directly on $scope.

Comment: could you explain last phraze? Why I cannot write ng-init="someVar='{{ twig_object | json_encode() }}';" and it will initialize $scope.someVar with twig_object ? Mean the double-dot principle.

Comment: The principle is okay, but the code wouldn't work, see my answer below for the correct code to get this working

Answer (score 4):

Well your options are limited in this case. If you don't want to make extra call then you will have to inject data into page as global variable (@JMK gives one more useful way with `ngInit`). It can be simple variable, but I find it more convenient to write it in form of some object and set a constant service from this global value. After that this constant can be used throughout the app.

```
<script>
window.config = {{ twig_object | json_encode() }};
</script>
```

Then create a constant (or `value`):

```
app.constant('config', {data: window.config});
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'config', function($scope, config) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.someVar = config.someVar;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: is it possible to initialize $scope.someVar without calling ng-init, like maybe in constructor of the controller ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you still need somehow to write this data into your controller. If your app is inside of the separate js file then you again need to write it into HTML as global variable or as ng-init on some element.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think this is the easiest working solution:

```
<div ng-init='somevar = {{ somevar|raw|replace({"'":"\\'"}) }}'>
```

Comment: This code introduces XSS vulnerability thrugh the somevar variable.